# React native Error while updating property 'X' in shadow node of type: RCTView

Tags: build.gradle, react-native

I am building a simple app and it works fine in the emulator(Genymotioin), but when I run it on real device it shows me an error.

> Error while updating property 'height' in shadow node of type: RCTView null
>   Unknown value: 200

What is odd for me is just it is running simply on emulator but not working on a real device.
And also I searched all the style with height. And there is no syntax error
i.e height: '22'
All the style with height is the integer not string. and there are no prop-types for that.
I cannot find where this error comes from.
So please suggest any idea to fix it. I will be happy if anyone helps me out to solve this problem.

P.S.
When I clean the gradle and generate apk, everything is okay but if I install that apk file on my phone, it is killed automatically.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpINc.png)

Comment: Is there anyone who has a solution for this? @DayOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this issue.
I downgrade the version of React native to 0.55.4
And everything else.
And I got succeed to build on my physical device.

But it might not be a great solution for everyone.

[**Update**]

If the version is not an issue for this case, Please consider updating the value which was in the Error.
For this case, I updated the property

**height: '55'** to **height: 55**

String -> Integer

Hope it could help.

Comment: I can say this could not be a global solution, But hopefully, this issue could be fixed.

Comment: Also if you change string value which indicates that property(e.g: height) to integer, it might be fixed.